# Remove <tr> tag dynamically by ID in C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html-table

I am having a issue there I have this table with bunch of information in it they have under lines and etc there are 3 images they are dependant of some  conditions and such. Here is the code:

```
 <table id="Table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="661" border="0" class="auto-style3">

  <tr>

    <td align="center"><img alt="" src="../images" id="sign1" runat="server" style="height:80px" />
      <asp:Label ID="lblUnderline1" runat="server" Text="____________________________"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="center"><img alt="" src="../images/" id="sign2" runat="server" style="height:80px" />
      <asp:Label ID="lblUnderline2" runat="server" Text="____________________________"></asp:Label>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" runat="server" id="Extra"><img alt="" src="../images" style="height:80px" id="sign3" runat="server" /><br />
      <asp:Label ID="lblUnderline3" runat="server" Text="____________________________"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" runat="server" Text="Vice President"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <asp:Label ID="lblTitle2" runat="server" Text=" Registrar"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Looks something like this:

[image: This image]

If you see there is a big Gap in between the Sign1 and the line on top where its suppose to be right under. There is the 3rd image that's hidden it only comes out when the if statement says `If(This condition){sign3.visible =true` But the gap between the line and the title is not going away I have tried this:

```
// Extra is the <tr> ID
     Extra.Visible = false;                     Extra.Style.Add("display", "none");
                    Extra.Style.Add("width", "0px");
```

So is there a way to remove the whole tag  out of the HTML from c# in a if condition such like

```
    If(Condition This)
{
// Remove the <tr> Tag along the image in it 
}
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to add a unique class to the TR that you want to hide, then add styles for that TR in your css file.

Right now, it looks like the TR has a height of 80px by default that you never remove. If you do not want to create/modify the css stylesheet you will need to add Extra.Style.Add("height","0px");

Comment: I added the high style like you mentioned  as well didn't work and then I removed the default 80px it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So As I looked through your code here it looks like you are trying to hide the `td` that's inside a `<tr>' yeah that worked it hides the
<td id=Extra but it doesnt hide the <tr` so try hiding the <`tr>`

```
<tr runat="server" id="Extra" >
<td align="center" ><img alt="" src="../images" style="height:80px" id="sign3" runat="server" /><br />
  <asp:Label ID="lblUnderline3" runat="server" Text="____________________________"></asp:Label>
</td>
```

This will work with your current dynamic conditions

```
    Extra.Visible = false;               
  Extra.Style.Add("display", "none");
       Extra.Style.Add("width", "0px");Extra.Style.Add("height", "0px"); // Even this as your default height is 80px
```

Comment: Oh yeah that was the issue now it removed the <tr> with every thing in it! Thanks